# How to properly display names of directories and their subdirectories from a linked list?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list, tree

Im trying to store the names of directories and sub directories in a linked list. Something like a basic DOS commands (mkdir, cd.., cd dir, dir, and delete). I would like to make a dir funcntion to display the subdirectories of the current directory. I just have no idea how to implement that. I made push and pop functions for stack as well. Can you help me out please?
**MY CODE:**

```html
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX_DIR_LENGTH (256)

typedef struct dir* Position;
typedef struct stack* StackPosition;

struct dir {
    char name[MAX_DIR_LENGTH];
    Position sibling;
    Position child;
    Position next;
};
struct stack {
    Position dir;
    StackPosition next;
};

Position createDir(char* name) {
    Position dir = (Position)malloc(sizeof(dir));
    if (!dir) {
        printf("Memory allocation failed!\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    strcpy(dir->name, name);
    dir->child = NULL;
    dir->sibling = NULL;
}

void push(char x, StackPosition S) {
    StackPosition q;
    q = (StackPosition)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));

    q->dir = x;

    q->next = S->next;
    S->next = q;
}
int pop(StackPosition S) {
    int x = -1;
    StackPosition temp;
    if (S->next != NULL) {
        x = S->next->dir;
        temp = S->next;
        S->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return x;
}

int md(Position current, char* name) {
    if (current->child == NULL) {
        current->child = createDir(name);

        //if (!dir)return-1;
    }
    else {
        Position dir = createDir(name);
        if (!dir)return -1;

        if (strcmp(current->child->name, name) > 0) {
            dir->sibling = current->child;
            current->child = dir;
        }
        else {
            Position tmp = current->child;

            while (strcmp(tmp->sibling->name, name) < 0) {
                tmp = tmp->sibling;
            }
            dir->next = tmp->next;
            tmp->next = dir;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
Position cd(Position current, char* name, StackPosition stack) {
    Position p = current->child;

    while (p != NULL && strcmp(p->name, name) != 0) {
        p = p->sibling;
    }
    if (!p) {
        printf("Directory not found, please try again!\n");
        return current;
    }

    push(name, stack);
    return p;
}
Position cdBack(StackPosition stack, Position current) {
    if (stack->next != NULL) {
        StackPosition first = stack->next;
        Position result = first->dir;
        stack->next = first->next;
        free(first);
        return result;
    }
    return current;
}
void delete(Position current) {
    if (!current)return;

    delete(current->sibling);
    delete(current->child);
    free(current);
}

int main() {
    char c;
    char ime[MAX_DIR_LENGTH];

    Position root = NULL;
    Position current = NULL;
    struct stack stack;
    
    stack.next = NULL;
    root = createDir("C:");
    current = root;

    //md(current, "John");
    
    //current = cdBack(&stack, current);

    while (1)
    {
        printf("1->mkdir\n2->cd dir\n3->cd..\n4->dir\n5->Izlaz\nYour choice: ");
        scanf("%c", &c);
        printf("\n");
        switch (c) {
        case'1':
            printf("Enter name:");
            scanf("%s", ime);
            md(current, ime);

            break;
        case'2':
            printf("Enter the directory where you want to enter:");
            scanf("%s",ime);
            cd(current, ime, &stack);
            break;
        case'3':
            current = cdBack(&stack, current);
            break;
        case'4':
            break;
        case'5':
            return 0;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain exactly where you are stuck.

Comment: I don't know how to use stack in this problem and dont know how to make display function to display subdirectories when i am in the certain directory. (e.g. cd in command prompt)